# HTML batch save into folder - Any ideas?

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-helper

I am trasferring some old 'inhouse' html sites to a new system.

The current folder structure is that all htmls of all sites are in one folder, and all the images of all those site are in /images folder.

Ofcourse i need to have seperate folders for each html and its images.

Just before writing some code to do the Job : Is anyone familiar with some library, solution or any idea to automate this without writing code?

Comment: To automate  what exactly? The downloading?

Comment: Are you doing this on a single machine, or on machines with network access to each other, or is FTP involved?

Comment: Everything is totaly local. And yes, i just need to automate what i can do with the 'save as' (complete html,not htm) from ie. Its just about 1000 sites, so it could be a drag.....

Comment: I don't know of a utility but you could probably, if you are on windows, use xcopy or robocopy to achieve this pretty easily, depending on what the destination folder structure needs to be. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY

Comment: Copying multiple files is easy. The thing is that i need to have each site specific images drawn out of the global images folder into a dedicated folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, needed to write some parsing code for that as i found no utility that could do that specificly.